# How do you get the Excavator badge?

Tags: support, badges

I have edited some posts of mine and others which are older than a year, including modifying some tags, but I did not get the badge. How exactly do you get it? Does it have to be precisely inactive for six months?

Comment: Has it been 24 hours since you did what you think should have earned you the badge? See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172258/263383, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1716/263383

Comment: Related: *[What are the badges I can earn on each site, and what are the exact criteria for earning each badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Edits to your own post, like [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/409345/revisions) do not count; see the answer to [Should I have earned an "Excavator" badge for this?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115012/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange.
- Tag-only edits like [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/301131/revisions) don't count either; you have to edit the body of the post (and/or the title if it's a question). See [Do tag edits count for Archaeologist?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126624/295232)

Comment: And, in addition: let it sit for a bit. The scripts that calculate badge awards run periodically and not constantly, so it can take a few hours for the badges to be awarded.